# Marklogic Search Using java

Tags: java, search, marklogic

Document that i have pumped from one network to my network using mlcp are not searching through java but the document that i have uploaded from my computer are being searched(ie)String search.the above are solved by using POSTMAN but i need solution in java`/*

```
public class Example_16_SearchString {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // create the client
    DatabaseClient client = 
      DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(Config.host, Config.port, 
        Config.user, Config.password, Config.authType);

    // create a manager for searching
    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();

    // create a search definition
    StringQueryDefinition query = queryMgr.newStringDefinition();

    query.setCriteria("189638");

    // create a handle for the search results
    SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();

    // run the search
    queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);

    // Format the results
    TutorialUtil.displayResults(resultsHandle);

    // release the client
    client.release();
  }
}

public class TutorialUtil {

  public static void displayResultURIs(SearchHandle resultsHandle) {
    // Get the list of matching documents in this page of results
    MatchDocumentSummary[] results = resultsHandle.getMatchResults();

    System.out.println("Listing " + results.length + " documents:");

    // List the URI of each matching document
    for (MatchDocumentSummary result : results) {
      System.out.println(result.getUri());
    }
  }

  public static void displayJSONResultDocs(
    SearchHandle resultsHandle, DatabaseClient client) 
  {
    JSONDocumentManager mgr = client.newJSONDocumentManager();

    // iterate over the result documents
    MatchDocumentSummary[] results = resultsHandle.getMatchResults();
    System.out.println("Listing " + results.length + " documents:\n");
    for (MatchDocumentSummary result : results) {
      StringHandle content = new StringHandle();
      mgr.read(result.getUri(), content);
      System.out.println(content.get());
    }
  }

  public static void displayResults(SearchHandle resultsHandle) {
    System.out.println("Matched " + resultsHandle.getTotalResults() + " documents\n");

    // Get the list of matching documents in this page of results
    MatchDocumentSummary[] results = resultsHandle.getMatchResults();
    System.out.println("Listing " + results.length + " documents:\n");

    // Iterate over the results
    for (MatchDocumentSummary result : results) {

      // get the list of match locations for this result
      MatchLocation[] locations = result.getMatchLocations();
      System.out.println("Matched " + locations.length + " locations in " + result.getUri() + ":");

      // iterate over the match locations
      for (MatchLocation location : locations) {

        // iterate over the snippets at a match location
        for (MatchSnippet snippet : location.getSnippets()) {
          boolean isHighlighted = snippet.isHighlighted();

          if (isHighlighted)
            System.out.print("[");
          System.out.print(snippet.getText());
          if (isHighlighted)
            System.out.print("]");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what request you create in POSTMAN that works?  That way we could compare.  Your Java code looks fine to me.

Comment: In addition, please confirm that you are using the exact same user for both solutions.

Comment: Authorization : Digest username="admin", realm="public", nonce="", uri="/LATEST/search?q=10325", response="e354cc11b575789f4af1ecc97bf22f22", opaque=""
accept  : multipart/mixed                                                                                                      url : GET : http://localhost:8011/LATEST/search?q=10325

Comment: Did you notice that your query string (10325) is different from the one in your code (189638)?

Comment: Yes , Authorization : Digest username="admin", realm="public", nonce="", uri="/LATEST/search?q=189638", response="e354cc11b575789f4af1ecc97bf22f22", opaque="" accept : multipart/mixed url : GET : localhost:8011/LATEST/search?q=189638.though i use same . Results is not available in java.